# How to fix CS0200 in C# program?

Tags: c#, readonly

I know that accordingly Microsoft support I should not use `readonly`, but I didn't.

The error CS0200 is shown on lines trying to update individual characters in the string:

> "unable to assign value to property or indexer".

```
    private string Start { set; get; }
    private string Middle { set; get; }
    private string Finish { set; get; }
    private string Alpha { set; get; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Alpha = "абвгґдеєжзиіїйклмнопрстуфхцчшщьюя";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Start = textBox1.Text;
        Middle = "абвгґдеєжзиіїйклмнопрстуфхцчшщьюя";
        for(int i = 0; i < Start.Length; i++ )
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Middle.Length ;j++)
            {
                if (Start[i] == Middle[j])
                {
                    char el = Middle[i]; 
                    Middle[i] = Middle[j]; // CS0200 
                    Middle[j] = el;        // CS0200 
                }       
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And which line produces the error?  If I were to *guess*, it's the lines assigning values to indexes in `Middle`.  But `Middle` is a `string`, you can't modify a string like that.  Perhaps what you want instead is a character array?

Comment: Strings are immutable. You can read an individual character by index, but you can't modify it.

Comment: Middle[i] = Middle[j]; and the next one.

Comment: What should I do if the strings are incompatible for this task? How can I make them changeble

Comment: Did you imply char array?

Comment: I think you should use a `StringBuilder` - seems right for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable, you cannot change them like this.
Use `StringBuilder` to make another string with changed characters, for example:

```
if (Start[i] == Middle[j])
{
    StringBuilder sb = new (Middle);
    (sb[i], sb[j]) = (sb[j], sb[i]);
    Middle = sb.ToString();
}
```

or even better - declare `Middle` as `StringBuilder` from the beginning, this will reduce string -> StringBuilder -> string conversions.
Char array is also an option if you only swap characters and never remove / add any.